# c++, JSON array parsing using nlohmann::json

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

In a json file imported into my c++ program there is such structure as:

```
{
 "a":"1",
 "ec":[
       {
        "a":"0x00",
        "s":[
             {"a":"0xA0"},
             {"a":"0xA1"},
            ],
        "b":"v1"
       },
       {
        "a":"0x01",
        "s":[
             {"a":"0xB0"},
             {"a":"0xB1"},
            ],
        "b":"v2"
       }
      ]
}
```

I want to iterate over the `"ec"` array and get the values of all `"a"` and for each `"a"` the same for its `s` array

```
vector<string> ec_a; // should contain {"0x00","0x01"}
vector<string> a1_s; // should contain {"0xA0", "0xA1"}
vector<string> a2_s; // should contain {"0xB0","0xB1"}
```

first I get the size of `ec` but from the [docs](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a875585b0cb6133902066daccd7c9d420.html#a875585b0cb6133902066daccd7c9d420) I understood should use iterator for the rest

```
int n=j["ec"].size() // n = 2
for(auto it=j["ec"].begin();it!=j["ec"].end();++it){
  if(it.key() == "a") ec_a.push_back(it.value());
}
```

but get this exception `nlohmann::detail::invalid_iterator at memory location` 
I assume that `j["ec"].begin()` is incorrect.

how should I do that, Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

`it` is an iterator to a compound type. A compound type doesn't, by itself, have a "key."

What you are trying to achieve is much easier than you may have thought. You can try this:

```
std::vector<std::string> ec_a;
for (auto& elem : j["ec"])
    ec_a.push_back(elem["a"]);
```

[**(live demo)**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eVMudJOCrhrxIslv)

Comment: consider adding `const` before `auto`